# react native passing data to other screen

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native .what I want is that in my app there is many images in each menu .when I click on the image I want to view the image in the screen size .the thing is when I click on every image I want it to Direct to a single page and call the image from there ..how is it possible to pass image variable from different pages to a single page..the so far did image view single page render is like below:,when the image component is did so it only views the first image not the other .what is the solution?

```
render() {
 this.state.incident = this.props.navigation.getParam('incidents','hi!!');
    this.state.tenantattachedagreement = this.props.navigation.getParam('tenantattach','hi!!!')
    // this.state.residents = this.props.navigation.getParam('residents','');
    // this.state.tenantattachedagreement = this.props.navigation.getParam('attachedagreement','');
    // console.log("attached agreement",this.state.tenantattachedagreement);
    // incidents = this.props.navigation.getParam('incidents,'');
    // console.log("hello",attached);
    // console.log("l&f pic",this.state.lostfound);
    console.log("incidentpic",this.state.incident);
    console.log("tenantattach",this.state.tenantattachedagreement);

    // console.log("residents",this.state.residents);



    return (
       <View style={{flex:1}}>
             <StatusBar 
       barStyle = "light-content"
       hidden = {false}
       backgroundColor = "#32ACFD"
       translucent = {false}
       networkActivityIndicatorVisible = {true}
       /> 
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row',height:50,width:'100%',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',backgroundColor:'#32ACFD',elevation:5,borderBottomWidth:1,borderColor:'#5b9bd5'}}>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.props.navigation.goBack()}} style={{height:'100%',width:'12%',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
               <Icon name="angle-left" style={{fontSize:25,color:'white'}}/>
             </TouchableOpacity>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.props.navigation.navigate('DashBoard')}} style={{width:'33%',height:'100%',justifyContent:'center'}}>
               <Text style={{color:'white',fontSize:18,textShadowColor: 'grey',paddingLeft:'5%',fontWeight:'500',fontStyle:'normal',textShadowRadius:5,textShadowOffset: {width: -1, height: 1}}}>Smart Vitae</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
             <View style={{width:'35%',height:'100%',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
                <Text style={{color:'white'}}>Unit: {this.state.unitname}</Text>
             </View>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.props.navigation.navigate('Notification')}} style={{width:'10%',height:'100%',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
                <Icon name="bell-o" style={{color:'white',fontSize:22}}/>
             </TouchableOpacity>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}} style={{width:'10%',height:'100%',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
                 <Icon name="cog" style={{color:'white',fontSize:24}}/>
             </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        <View>
                <View style={{height:'100%',width:'100%',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',borderColor:'#2E4053'}}>  

                              <Image source={{uri:this.state.residents}} style={{height:'100%',width:'100%'}}></Image>
                              <Image source={{uri:this.state.lostfound}} style={{height:'100%',width:'100%'}}></Image> 
                              <Image source={{uri:this.state.tenantattachedagreement}} style={{height:'100%',width:'100%'}}></Image> 
                              <Image source={{uri:this.state.incident}} style={{height:'100%',width:'100%'}}></Image>            
                </View>
        </View>                     

       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a styling issue, you have multiple images all trying to fill 100%

```
<Image source={{uri:this.state.residents}} style={{height:'100%',width:'100%'}}></Image>
```

Try using `flex` or updating your height, like this:

```
<Image source={{uri:this.state.residents}} style={{height:'25%',width:'100%'}}></Image>
```

Comment: thanx I am getting all the image viewed but it appears as if small what if I want it in the screen height.also it is viewing to a portion of the screen

Comment: You need to decide how you want to present multiple images at fullscreen size. If you want them to scroll you should wrap your images in a scroll view or better yet use a flatlist

Comment: it is that only that image should be viewed in full size on which image we click so is there a need of flatlets or scroll view

Comment: You can try creating a new route with a single image at 100%, then you can pass the uri of the clicked image to this new route. That way the user can press back when they want to select the next image